# How to overly an image with a cropped photo from camera in iOS

Tags: ios, image, camera, overlay

I am just learning to create an app and I am using Smartface since there is GUI. In a page I created, there is a "Camera" button and "Gallery" button. There is also an image with a blank face.

I hope you can see this link:
http://filesxpress.com/d-160a75e1

What I am trying to do is open the camera function when the user taps the "Camera" button, and the user then captures a photo (of a person).

After the capture, the image will be cropped.

I have done that part by utilizing codes in stackoverflow and in the Smartface site as well. See code below:

```
function Scene1_Self_OnKeyPress(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 4) {
    Dialogs.Scene1.close();
    }
}
function Scene1_btnCamera_OnTouch(e){
    SMF.Multimedia.startCamera({
    cameraType : 1, //rear camera
    resolution : 2, //large resolution
    autoFocus : true,
    onStart : function () {}, //do nothing
    onCapture : function (e) {
    alert("path=" + e.photoUri);
   },
    onCancel : function () {}, //do nothing
    onFailure : function () {} //do nothing
   });
  }

var photoUri = "";
  SMF.Multimedia.startCamera(1, 2, 1,
  function (e) {},
  function (e) {
    photoUri = e.photoUri;
    SMF.UI.cropImage({
        imageUri : photoUri,
        options : {
            aspectX : 1,
            aspectY : 1,
            outputX : 500,
            outputY : 500
        },
        onSuccess : function (e) {
            // e.imageUri
            // e.width
            // e.height
            Device.Media.saveToGallery({
                item : e.imageUri,
                onSuccess : function (e) {
                    alert("The image is saved to the gallery.");
                },
                onError : function (e) {
                    alert("error: " + e.message);
                }
      });
      },
      onError : function (e) {
      // e.message
      },
      onCancel : function (e) {
      alert("The camera is cancelled");
      }
    });
  },
   function (e) {},
   function (e) {}
  );
```

Here are the things that I need assistance with:

1. When the captured picture is being cropped, only a 9-cell table appears that helps the resizing. Is there a way to show up that image with a blank face, and the user will then position the captured image to be cropped at the back of that image? (It has transparency)
2. When the image is positioned properly at the back of the blank face, the user can then SAVE the image and the result shall be the blank face + the inserted or the cropped and overlaid image.

Thank you very much for your help.